# Android Beam - NFC - Incorrect message sent with beam

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, android-beam

I'm trying to create communication between a Android phone (Galaxy S2 plus NFC) and a PN532.
This communication works fine and I can transmit data in the two directions.

I have a recent problem probably due to the publication of the application on the Play Store. Few days ago, I could create my NDEF message and it was sent by calling `nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(message, this)`.

But now, the message sent is the address of my application on the Play Store... I receive two NDEF records in an NDEF message :

- First NDEF record : TNF = NFC RTD Well-Known
  "play.google.com/store/..."
- Second one : TNF = Absolute URI type = "android.com:pkg", payload = "mypackagename"

I really don't understand why I receive these data and not my own NDEF message... I haven't changed anything important in the application since the application was working fine (just publication in Play Store).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a Android Beam bug... If you have the same problem, you just have to reboot the smartphone.